# In regex, How to get the only value?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

```
DeviceName=
ssid=VDS23
distance=98
regioncode=2013BS

/*Expect value*/
2013BS
```

Is there any regex? 
I tried \=\b(.*)\b\w but problem is it contains '=' character and
it prints all the values.(I want to print 2013BS only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the value from the `regioncode` key only, then use the following pattern:

```
regioncode=(.*)
```

The value of this key will be available in the first capture group.  I have assumed that the regex tool/engine you are using has dot in a mode which does not capture newlines.

### Demo

If the entire pattern you use will determine what gets returned, then you can use the following pattern with a lookaround:

```
(?<=regioncode=)(.*)
```

This would only match the value corresponding to the `regioncode` key.

Comment: I have one more question. Javascript is not supported lookbehind. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: If you can't use lookarounds then you need to match the entire pattern.  But if you are using JS then what is the problem with a little string work to get what you need?